# Is there such thing as a weak_ptr that can't be locked (promoted to shared_ptr)? If not, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, weak-ptr

Maybe this question has been asked before, but I've never found a satisfactory answer. Also, for the purposes of simplicity assume I'm talking about a single-threaded application.

So, what I've heard a number of times is that if you have an object that is **non-owned** and whose **lifetime is guaranteed**, you should reference it with a raw pointer. The object's owner would use a unique_ptr, and hand out raw pointers as necessary.

But what if the object is **non-owned**, and the **lifetime is *not* guaranteed**? Then you can use a weak_ptr, yes. But then anyone who is handed a weak_ptr could be naughty and keep it locked, such that the object's owner can't cause the object to be destroyed. Sometimes this may not be a problem, but sometimes it is. For example, when the owned object represents some system resource which *must* be relinquished at a certain time.

You may say "well, then you should just make sure no one keeps the weak_ptr locked!" But that is just not ideal (in my opinion) from an OO design standpoint, as it creates a dependency between the "owner" object and any object that gets a weak_ptr from it. You might as well make the argument "you don't need to return const references; you should just make sure no one modifies the reference."

With Qt, you have the QPointer, which is basically what I'm looking for. It checks that the object hasn't been destroyed, but it can't *prevent* the object from being destroyed. I realize this isn't thread-safe, but again, I'm talking about the context of a single thread.

So why isn't there something similar for C++11? I'm sure I could make a wrapper around weak_ptr that accomplishes what I'm after. But I wonder if I'm going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with pure Standard C++ using `shared_ptr<unique_ptr<T>>`.

Observers received only a `shared_ptr<const unique_ptr<T>>`, allowing them to look but not touch.  The owner, having a non-`const` smart pointer, can at any time call `reset()` on the `unique_ptr` to destroy the instance.  At that time all the observers can also see that the `unique_ptr` has become empty.

Obvious threading and re-entrance caveats apply (you need to check the `unique_ptr` for having a valid pointer again after each callback you invoke, etc).

And if there should be multiple owners, it's a bit more work.  You will need one `shared_ptr<T*>`, giving observers a `shared_ptr<T* const>`.  And a separate `shared_ptr<T>` to manage the object lifetime.  The `shared_ptr<T*>` will need to be manually filled with `nullptr` (The `T*`, not the `shared_ptr`) in the object's destructor.

Comment: The `shared_ptr<unique_ptr>` combo is clever. +1 for teaching me something new today (even though I can't imagine using it, it just can come in handy, and worth knowing about!). However, re `shared_ptr<const shared_ptr<T>>`, note that a `const shared_ptr` does not prevent changes of the reference count, thus, it does not prevent the prolonged lifetime that the OP is concerned about.

Comment: Okay, problems. One is the problem David Scwartz focuses on, that of the object disappearing mid-call. That problem can be avoided with an ordinary direct `shared_ptr`, where client code can guarantee continued object existence during a call. More serious problem: that either the usage will be awkward due to the extra indirection, or else one adds a simplification layer, in which case that layer could just as well just check an ordinary `weak_ptr` (i.e. like the code in my answer)?

Comment: @Alf: Your `if (p)` is rather nice compared to `if (*p)`, but `auto ptr = p.ptr_or_null();` vs `auto& ptr = *p;` is not less awkward.  And one should probably go with `if (auto& ptr = *p) { /* use p->members */ }` anyway

Comment: Although I greatly appreciate all answers (and have learned something from each of them), I'm accepting this one as it uses pure C++ and is closest to what I was asking for. Pretty clever solution, I can't believe I didn't think of it before.

Answer (score 6):

No. And it doesn't exist is because it's unsafe even for a single thread. Consider:

```
void some_function (super_weak_ptr foo)
{
    foo->some_function();
}
```

What happens if `some_function` (through an indirect path) causes the object to be destroyed? And before you say that can never happen, yes it can. For example:

```
void got_some_data (some_type whatObject, some_other_type whatData)
{
    super_weak_ptr object = findObject (whatObject);
    if (object)
        object->youGotMail (whatData);        
}
```

Now, suppose the `youGotMail` function realizes that the object now got the last bit of data it needs and its job is complete, it might destroy that object, and now we're running a function on an object that no longer exists.

If you want a raw pointer, you know where to find one. It doesn't make much sense to create a "smart" pointer that's no safer than a raw pointer.

So if you're not managing the lifetime of an object, you need the ability to lock that object before you can do anything to that object.

Comment: This argument would mean, never to hand out a raw pointer, it could be unsafe. Yet C++ programmers take that risk routinely.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is also common to advise people never to hand out a raw pointer, and it certainly doesn't seem to make sense to create a "smart" pointer that's actually no safer than a raw pointer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The proposed alternative to `weak_ptr` is basically a raw pointer. If you want a raw pointer, then just use a raw pointer. Don't put lipstick on it and pretend that it's something better than it is.

Comment: @RaymondChen: No, the OP is not proposing a raw-pointer-like thing. He's asking about a thing that can detect object existence and hand out a raw pointer or null, as shown e.g. in my answer's example code. With only a raw pointer you can't easily check for object existence.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf With what he's proposing, you always have a race condition because you have the raw pointer but no way to keep the object in existence, and you don't control its lifetime. So it is a raw-pointer-like thing. If you don't control something's lifetime, you need a way to keep it alive while you mess with it, and this doesn't provide one, so it's raw-pointer-like.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You raise a valid concern, but it is not insurmountable.  One, the `youGotMail` member function should only destroy itself if it no longer needs the `this` object, that's not a problem with the caller, but with any object that performs a `delete this;` directly or indirectly.  Two, `got_some_data` should assume that its weak pointer may have changed whenever it calls external code, and check it again.  So none of `if (object) { f(object.get()); g(object.get()); }`, but it is safe to `if (object) f(object.get()); if (object) g(object.get());`

Comment: @BenVoigt The thing is, it only does a `delete this` because the smart pointer isn't smart. If you used a regular `weak_ptr`, then the delete would never happen because the caller would have temporary ownership of the object. You can't call a function on an object whose ownership you don't control without some mechanism to ensure the object isn't destroyed while you're trying to operate on it. It's the fact that `std::weak_ptr` provides that mechanism that makes it a safe weak pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt `youGotMail` might not explicitly destroy `this`, but it could call to some other method that in turn destroys the object. For example, maybe `youGotMail` displays a properties window, and while the window is being displayed, the user deletes the item. Now, `youGotMail` is operating on a destroyed `this`. In order for this to be safe, you need to keep a strong reference on the object to prevent it from being destroyed out from under you.

Comment: @Raymond, but then the error lies in youGotMail and the implementation of the callback it invokes. The starting assumption was that the object's owner, not its use count, decides when to destroy it -- for this to work it must do so only at controlled points where it can guarantee no outstanding operations are using it. The weak pointer is neither helping nor hurting with that lifetime management issue.

Comment: @BenVoigt The weak pointer helps because promoting it to a strong pointer, which you must do to operate on the object, ensures the object isn't removed. If you don't manage the lifetime but some other code does, you have to somehow ensure the object isn't removed while you call functions on it. The `weak_ptr` allows you to do that by promoting it to a strong pointer. Without that, there would be no safe way to use it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The question explicitly excludes that solution.  Contrary to your continual claims, there is another solution, which is to prevent object destruction during a reentrant call.  For example, when the object reaches zero count, instead of destroying it immediately, destruction could be pended to an event queue.  That way destruction never occurs during processing of any event, handlers for other events need only check on entry whether the objects they intend to use are alive or dead.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You may say this is the same as allowing the user to add a reference count to the object, but it is not.  There is no way for a user to force the object to stay alive across multiple events, or potentially leak a reference.  The owner has full control over lifetime, to the granularity of the event queue.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not saying it's impossible to use such a thing correctly. Only that it doesn't provide the guarantees that you typically need and so the cost/benefit tradeoff is strongly against it.

Comment: @BenVoigt If you know that the object's lifetime will never end during the call to `youGotMail`, then the weak pointer doesn't really buy you anything. Weak pointers are for when you do not know the lifetime.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Faulty logic.  That "'object is alive when youGotMail is called' implies 'object is alive when youGotMail returns'" does not tell you whether 'object is alive prior to call of youGotMail' is true or false.  The weak pointer is a safe way for all potential users to discover whether the target has been destroyed, AND which also cleans up the metadata when no potential users remain.  That's not less useful simply because the object can only be destroyed at synchronization points.

Comment: Not to add fuel to the fire, but I think Ben sees what I'm getting at. The example isn't really sufficient, because if `youGotMail` does `delete this`, that's a flaw with `youGotMail`. And if `youGotMail` somehow indirectly causes the owner to delete the object, then I have a circular dependency somewhere, which is also an independent problem.

Comment: The advantage that this `super_weak_ptr` provides is that if I check that it's not null, I have a guarantee that the object is safe to use *in the remainder of that scope*, provided that the object is only used in one thread and I don't have any aforementioned circular dependencies. I think part of the problem here is that I'm coming from a Qt mindset, where "only is used in one thread" is a safe assumption most of the time.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter The problem is that it's very hard to be sure you don't have any of these circular dependencies. When you use smart pointers, any code that throws away a reference can potentially destroy the object and code that you normally expect to destroy the object may wind up not destroying it because some other bit of code still has a strong pointer to it, resulting in code you didn't expect to destroy the object later destroying it. We use smart pointers so these things don't bite us and the suggested "very weak pointer" would be very hard to use safely.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ah, I see. I'm used to dealing with code with pretty strong hierarchical relationships between objects, so circular dependencies aren't an issue. But I can see that using smart pointers effectively would allow you to have different kinds of relationships between objects that would remain safe. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing, alas.

In 2009 I [toyed with / explored such a smart pointer type](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++/friend-declaration-not-accepted-by-msvc/1047552) that I called `ZPtr`, as I recall as a cleanup effort of some earlier code in that direction, in the context of supporting better file abstraction error handling than the silence treatment of the standard library's iostreams. The (earlier) idea was to not have any zombie objects around, by self-destroying when no further meaningful operations were possible, and this required access via a smart pointer that could detect the existence or not of the referent. Evidently it was not such a good idea at the time, because the article I sent to DDJ about it was rejected … by the silence treatment.

I think now that we have argument forwarding support in the language, the time for such a pointer may have come. It would be even better with possible overloading of the `.` operator. But the functionality will anyway have to be chosen very carefully.

---

The `std::weak_ptr` isn't really "locked", in spite of naming. It's just used to obtain a `std::shared_ptr`, if possible. And a `std::shared_ptr` readily supplies you with a raw pointer.

So you can choose to hand out not `std::weak_ptr` directly, but a wrapper that only provides a temporary raw pointer.

It will not be very thread safe though, and unlike a `ZPtr` it will not give the client code any idea of why the referent doesn't exist any more (when it doesn't). But it just may be all that you need. Let me get some coffee & a bite to eat, then I'll cook up an example.

---

Example:

```
#include <memory>

namespace cppx {
    using std::shared_ptr;
    using std::weak_ptr;

    template< class Type >
    class Poor_ptr
    {
    private:
        struct Null {};
        weak_ptr<Type>      weak_p_;

    public:
        explicit operator bool() const { return not is_null(); }

        friend
        auto operator==( const Poor_ptr& p, Poor_ptr::Null* )
            -> bool
        { return p.is_null(); }

        friend
        auto operator==( Poor_ptr::Null*, const Poor_ptr& p )
            -> bool
        { return p.is_null(); }

        friend
        auto operator!=( const Poor_ptr& p, Poor_ptr::Null* )
            -> bool
        { return not p.is_null(); }

        friend
        auto operator!=( Poor_ptr::Null*, const Poor_ptr& p )
            -> bool
        { return not p.is_null(); }

        auto is_null() const
            -> bool
        { return (ptr_or_null() == nullptr); }

        auto ptr_or_null() const
            -> Type*
        {
            try
            {
                return weak_p_.lock().get();
            }
            catch( ... )
            {
                return nullptr;
            }
        }

        auto ptr() const
            -> Type*
        { return weak_p_.lock().get(); }

        Poor_ptr( shared_ptr< Type > p )
            : weak_p_( p )
        {}
    };

}  // namespace cppx

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    auto p = make_shared<int>( 42 );
    cppx::Poor_ptr<int> pp = p;
    cout
        << "That " << pp.ptr_or_null() << " is null is "
        << (pp == 0) << ", not " << !!pp << ".\n";
    p.reset();
    cout
        << "That " << pp.ptr_or_null() << " is null is "
        << (pp == 0) << ", not " << !!pp << ".\n";
}
```

Oh, and to cover the problem that [David Schwartz mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28954503/464581), that of the object disappearing in mid-call of some function, you can just provide a member function that executes a functor such as `std::function` with a raw pointer as argument, where the referred to object is guaranteed kept alive during that call (namely by having a local `std::shared_ptr`).

Then the client code programmer can choose whether to rely on an assumption that called functions will not destroy the object, or use the safer callback mechanism.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think `not` is a good way to write boolean negation, and `!!` is a good Windows-idiomatic way to write conversion to `bool` (in a way that shuts up the Visual C++ compiler, lest it warns about performance…). Note for Visual C++: use a forced include of `<iso646.h>` to compile this code.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Possibly but not necessarily. Python is easily learned, I think (at least that's what they learn first at MIT nowadays). And it has `!=` and `not`. Learning C++ coming from Python, that would be very natural?

Comment: This is exactly the "wrapper around weak_ptr" solution I mentioned. Thanks for taking the time to actually write the code. And I like the idea of the ZPtr as well, I can see that being useful in particular circumstances.