# Any use for dynamically allocating std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Does it ever make sense to create a `std::unique_ptr` using `new`? In the snippet below as I suspected the `SimpleClass` object being managed by the `std::unique_ptr` won't be destroyed unless I delete the `std::unique_ptr` myself. I couldn't think of a situation where this is useful so I was wondering if there are situations where this is actually used.

```
  std::unique_ptr<vector_test::SimpleClass>* ptr_to_unique_ptr = new std::unique_ptr<vector_test::SimpleClass>();
  ptr_to_unique_ptr->reset(new vector_test::SimpleClass(555));
  delete ptr_to_unique_ptr;
```

Comment: I cannot think of a good use case for a raw pointer to a unique pointer to an object.  If I were to find such a use case, I think I would try to use a unique pointer to the unique pointer to the object.

Comment: What about using `std:unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<vector_test::SimpleClass>>`?

Comment: I can only think if you need shared ownership of the unique pointer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831775/making-shared-ptr-lose-ownership-of-memory

Comment: @Galik: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955443/103167 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510414/103167

Comment: I think this could just be named misuse. Every pros given by RAII would be neutralized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it ever make sense to create a `std::unique_ptr` using `new`?

Most probably not.

There's no concise reason why you would/should fall back to manual memory management while already using the standard [*dynamic memory allocation* techniques](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

> I couldn't think of a situation where this is useful so I was wondering if there are situations where this is actually used.

I can't timagine either about such situation.

Comment: Your link is missing a character at the end in the URL but good answer.

Comment: Thanks for notifying, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is rarely a use for dynamically allocating a singular pointer. Closest real word use case is a singly linked list, where we dynamically allocate a class instance that contains a pointer, and some data associated with the node. Although, need to implement a linked list is rare because it is rarely the optimal choice of data structure, and because the standard library already provides decent designs of linked list.

Note that if we were to dynamically allocate a (smart) pointer, there is no good reason to not use a smart pointer to manage that allocation.

Comment: Such situation can be boiled down using a `std::weak_ptr`, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure what situation you're suggesting. I haven't encountered good uses for weak pointers (although I don't doubt they exist).

Answer (score 1):

> Does it ever make sense to create a std::unique_ptr using new?

I can't think of. There are situations where you want to prevent an object managed through a `unique_ptr` from deletion, when the scope that contains the `unique_ptr` ends. There are several ways to do this, without having to `new` the `unique_ptr` itself.

Some examples:

1. Move the object to another `unique_ptr` in a different scope.

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<int> p1;
   {
       std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = std::make_unique<int>( 42 );
       p1 = std::move( p2 );
       // Destructor of p2 won't delete object, because ownership was transferred.
   }
   // Scope of p2 has ended, but object is still managed by p1.
   std::cout << *p1;
   ```
2. Return an object managed through a `unique_ptr` from a function.

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<int> MyFun() {
       std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>( 42 );
       return p;  // No explicit move required, because of RVO
   }
   ```
3. [Release](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) ownership and get the raw pointer back.

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>( 42 );
   some_C_API_that_takes_ownership( p.release() );
   // Destructor of p won't delete object, because ownership was given up.
   ```